# Conditional Probability | Please explain this answers

Tags: conditional-probability

Can you please explain Why P(W2) is 4/9 ?
Thanks.. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are searching for the white marbles and there are total 4 white marbles. And the total marbles you've got is 9. So it 4/9.

You don't actually need this method, You just need the probability of the second draw.Because the second draw is without replacement, Total marbles decrease by 1 and now the total is 8, because already a white marble is taken, total no. of white marbles left is 3. So the answer is 3/8. Easy...comment if there is any doubt.

Comment: But this is without replacement..so shouldn't we be choosing from a total of 8 on the second draw?

Comment: edited...@Memo check it out!

Comment: Yes the book this is from has Method 2 like you said..I just wanted to also understand the first method.Thanks.

Comment: you have to justify that the result remain true for the 2nd marble as well as for the first...